# Python script to calculate the Collatz conjecture

Tags: python, collatz-sequence

Here is the code.

```
# Collatz.py - The Collatz conjecture
initiate = True
while True:
    if initiate == True:
        initiate = False
        try:
            number = float(input('Enter a number: '))
        except:
            print('Error! Please try again.')
            number = 1
    if number % 2 == 0:
        number /= 2
    elif number == 1:
        if input('Quit? (y/n)') == 'y':
            break
        else:
            initiate = True
    else:
        number *= 3
        number += 1
    print(number,end='\n----\n')
```

Comment: This would be a better question if it explained what the Collatz conjecture is and how this calculates it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The output does not start with the number I enter, which I find a bit surprising.  Rather, the output starts with the following number in the Collatz sequence.

The Collatz sequence deals with integers, so why convert the input to a `float` rather than an `int`?  To catch invalid input, you should catch just `ValueError` rather than every kind of error.  Otherwise, you wouldn't even be able to exit the program using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>.  Also, since you are using Python 3, you should use the `//` operator for integer division instead of the `/` operator, which does floating-point division.

The `initiate` flag variable is awkward.  Also, the code for calculation, number input, and restarting are all mingled together.  I recommend splitting the Collatz calculation code into a generator function:

```
def collatz_seq(n):
    yield n
    while n != 1:
        n = (3 * n + 1) if (n % 2) else (n // 2)
        yield n

while True:
    try:
        start_num = int(input('Enter a number: '))
        for n in collatz_seq(start_num):
            print(n, end='\n====\n')
    except ValueError:
        print('Error! Please try again.')
    if 'y' == input('Quit (y/n)? '):
        break
```